If dropdown = value then bring in all instances of other dropdown?
I have a formula where I have it look at two dropdown values (c1 and d1) and bring in relevant data where those two values are found in two columns in 'Master Line List' worksheet.
it works as it should, but I added in a new value labeled "All" in d1 dropdown. If user selects "All" then bring in all statuses for that agent (ignore blanks for status column in 'Master Line List'). I have an expected result in the table starting in columns G:K.
Here is what I've tried:
=FILTER(
    IF(
        AND(D1 = "All", ISNUMBER(MATCH(C1, 'Master Line List'!I:I, 0))),
        'Master Line List'!A:I,
        CHOOSECOLS('Master Line List'!A:I, 3, 6, 9, 7, 1)
    ),
    IF(
        D1 = "All",
        ISNUMBER(MATCH(C1, 'Master Line List'!I:I, 0)),
        AND(
            'Master Line List'!I:I = C1,
            'Master Line List'!G:G = D1
        )
    ),
    'Master Line List'!G:G <> "",  // Excluding rows with blank in column G:G
    BYROW(
        'Master Line List'!F:F,
        LAMBDA(
            Σ,
            OR(
                BYCOL(
                    SPLIT(Σ, CHAR(10)),
                    LAMBDA(
                        Λ,
                        ISBETWEEN(
                            --LEFT(Λ, FIND(" ", Λ)),
                            G2,
                            H2
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

and here is my worksheet
Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

So if D1 is "All", the dropdown in C1 and dates in G2,H2 are all ignored?

@rockinfreakshow if d1 = 'All' I want all statuses (non-blanks) brought in from column G:G in 'Master Line List'. All other logic remains the same. If d1 = something like 'Outreach' then I want it to only bring in Outreach statuses for that agent and dates (c1 and G2/H2)

@rockinfreakshow Hey sorry, I just updated my expected table to reflect only rows where the comment dates have at least one comment that fits between start/end dates in g2:h2. good call out


You may try:
=filter(choosecols('Master Line List'!A:I,3,6,9,7,1), 'Master Line List'!I:I=C1, if(D1="All",'Master Line List'!G:G<>"",'Master Line List'!G:G=D1),
 byrow('Master Line List'!F:F,lambda(Σ,or(bycol(split(Σ,char(10)),lambda(Λ,isbetween(--left(Λ,find(" ",Λ)),G2,H2)))))))


**fully not matching with the given expected output for ALL
